# Time dimensions datawarehouse

Tags: data-warehouse

Currently I'm working on a BI project for school and I ran into some difficulties with my time dimension. Normally a time dimension is conformed, which means it can be used in multiple facts. But now I have a problem,, for some facts yearly data suffices, but others need weekly/monthly/quarterly/yearly data. Is it possible to relate the same time dimension, which structure is TIME(timeID, week, month, quarter, year) to these facts of different granularity levels?? Or should I make a year dimension for the facts that only need yearly data and a time dimension containing month etc. for the remaining facts?

Tnx for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

Use just one time dimension and tie the fact rows to the last day of the time period.So for example; on the yearly fact you reference the last-day-of-the-year-time dimension member.